# My book wrote a question "If $I_n =\int_0^\infty e^{2x}\sin^n x\;dx$,...", but when doing the integration wrote "$\int_0^{\pi/2}$...". Is it a typo?

Tags: calculus, integration

My book wrote a question that is

> If $I_n =\int_0^\infty e^{2x}\sin^n x\;dx$, $n\geq 1$ then prove that $(n^2+4)I_n=n(n-1)I_{n-2}2e^\pi$ and hence evaluate $I_3$.

But, when doing integration, they wrote
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}$$ And, other things respectively. Is that a typo?

[image]

I don't think they have did anything

Comment: You have to provide more information for the question to make sense. They may be using some change of variable in the proof.

Comment: Given there is a trig function it may relate to the fact that $tan(\pi/2)$ is infinite.

Comment: Based on what limited context you've given, I assume the typo was in the definition of $I_n$ and it should have been $\pi/2$, not $\infty$, initially.

Comment: I have edited my post...

Comment: @BrianMoehring /|\

Comment: what is the language? is it bengali?

Comment: @Algebrology Yes! There's English also..

Comment: I maintain my previous assumption.  The integral with upper limit $\infty$ doesn't even exist, and both the solution and the recursive expression only works for an upper limit of $\pi/2$.  For me, that's enough to conclude the original definition of $I_n$ in the problem statement had the typo.

Comment: *nod* It's perfectly clear that $I_{2n}$ diverges to infinity as its an exponential times a nonnegative function.   Pretty sure the $I_{2n+1}$ diverge due to oscillationso will bounce around wildly (if defined with $\infty$ terms0